# Plotting the effect of document pruning on text corpus in R text2vec

Tags: r, nlp, text2vec

Is it possible to check how many documents remain in the corpus after applying `prune_vocabulary` in the `text2vec` package?

Here is an example for getting a dataset in and pruning vocabulary

```
library(text2vec)
library(data.table)
library(tm)

#Load movie review dataset
data("movie_review")
setDT(movie_review)
setkey(movie_review, id)
set.seed(2016L)

#Tokenize
prep_fun = tolower
tok_fun = word_tokenizer
it_train = itoken(movie_review$review, 
              preprocessor = prep_fun, 
              tokenizer = tok_fun, 
              ids = movie_review$id, 
              progressbar = FALSE)


#Generate vocabulary
vocab = create_vocabulary(it_train
                      , stopwords = tm::stopwords())

#Prune vocabulary
#How do I ascertain how many documents got kicked out of my training set because of the pruning criteria?
pruned_vocab = prune_vocabulary(vocab, 
                            term_count_min = 10, 
                            doc_proportion_max = 0.5,
                            doc_proportion_min = 0.001)

# create document term matrix with new pruned vocabulary vectorizer
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(pruned_vocab)
dtm_train  = create_dtm(it_train, vectorizer)
```

Is there an easy way to understand how aggressive the `term_count_min` and `doc_proportion_min` parameters are being on my text corpus. I am trying to do something similar to how `stm` package lets us handle this using a `plotRemoved` function which produces a plot like this:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used for testing and verification.

Comment: I have added the MWE. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vocab $vocab` is a `data.table` which contains a lot of statistics about your corpus. `prune_vocabulary` with `term_count_min`, `doc_proportion_min` parameters just filters this `data.table`. For example here is how you can calculate number of removed tokens:

```
total_tokens = sum(v$vocab$terms_counts)
total_tokens
# 1230342
# now lets prune
v2 = prune_vocabulary(v, term_count_min = 10)
total_tokens - sum(v2$vocab$terms_counts)
# 78037
# effectively this will remove 78037 tokens
```

On other side you can create document-term matrices with different vocabularies and check different statistics with functions from `Matrix` package: `colMeans(), colSums(), rowMeans(), rowSums()`, etc. I'm sure you can obtain any of the metrics above.

For example here is how to find empty documents:

```
doc_word_count = Matrix::rowSums(dtm)
indices_empty_docs = which(doc_word_count == 0)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I was able to write a wrapper around the `prune_vocabulary` function to generate the token and word plots. Only the documents one is a little confusing. Can you please elaborate a little on how we can calculate how many documents remain in the corpus? One of the things I noticed is that the LDA implementation applies weights for even empty documents. I wonder if that can be avoided and I can manually remove empty document before running LDA using this approach.

Comment: Added example on how to find empty docs. For LDA this is probably an old [bug](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/issues/149) which was fixed in development version.